# how to parse this returned value in php

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time parsing this. I know how to get the key up to access_credentials by doing this: $account['twitter']->access_credentials;.

But I can't seem to get the oauth_token or oauth_token_secret. I need to get this so I can save it to my session variable.

```
[twitter] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [third_party_uid] => 
        [access_credentials] => {"oauth_token":"xxxx","oauth_token_secret":"xxx","user_id":"1234","screen_name":"user_1"}
        [mds_user_id] => 15
        [type] => 
        [provider] => Twitter
    )
```

Please help.

Comment: solve it, just needed to json_decode the result ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a JSON string. Decode it:

```
$credentials = json_decode($account['twitter']->access_credentials, true);
echo $credentials['oauth_token'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ac = json_decode($twitter->access_credentials);
echo $ac['oauth_token'];
```